# Change row background color while item be touch in ListView

Tags: android, listview

I try to use BaseAdapter to show item in ListView.
I try below code in BaseAdapter.

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //...
    convertView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
       switch(event.getAction()) {
         case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
         v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_corner_four_click);
     break;

         case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
         v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_corner_four);
     break;
     }

     return false;
     }
   });
}
```

While item be touched, it change background to ic_corner_four_click.
But while release finger or move to other item, it did not rechange to ic_corner_four.
How to modify it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a `StateListDrawable` to define the background in a specific state. [See the documentation.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList) If you look to the right of the question you can see other very similar questions. --->

[This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939838/change-the-background-image-of-listview-on-focus), for example.

Comment: iam using stateListDRawable. but when we scroll the list the selection goes off. why? how to fix that? i did lot searching and i tried "choice_mode_single" but i couldn't retain the highlight. any idea?

Comment: Ah, that's a different problem. I thought you just wanted a particular background on touch. If you want to do that it's a bit more complicated. You have to keep the selection position in a model and override the getView() method in the adapter to call `view.setSelected(true)` if the view is the selected one.

Answer (score 2):

The reason behind this problem is your `onTouch` function is always returning `false`. For `ACTION_DOWN` the code is executed and the function returns false. Now it is never called for `ACTION_UP`. Change return value to `true` should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the select mode in the list view

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE

```
listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```